# RestKit RKManagedObjectRequestOperation expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, core-data, restkit

First I tried to implement restKit without using core data. Everything worked. But now I want to implement core data also in it. I made a separate class where I put all my core data stuff and mapping stuff in.

I made a init function in it, that looks like this.

```
-(API *)init{

self = [super init];

if (self != nil){

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://virtuele-receptie.preview.sanmax.be"];

    AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];

    objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    _managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

    managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:_managedObjectModel];

    objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

}

return self;
```

}

Then I have a function mapLogin, which is gonna map my json into the core data entities.The only thing I changed in this method was from

```
RKObjectMapping *dataMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Data class]];
```

To

```
 RKEntityMapping* dataMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Data" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
```

Now when I run I get a giagantic log. But the most important things are there these I think.

**LOG**

```
W restkit:RKObjectManager.m:488 Asked to create an `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` object, but managedObjectStore is nil.

CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Data' 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Data 0x1fd0b390> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "status".'
```

**EDIT**
Oké, I putted the managedObjectstore after I intialized my RKObjectManager.

```
   objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
        objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
```

But now I got the following error.

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: self.managedObjectContext'
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating your managed object store do something like:

```
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"RKTwitter.sqlite"];
NSString *seedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RKSeedDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:seedPath withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
```